# Django, Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x00' in ValueQuerySet

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I tried to run the following code, I get the error:

**Django, Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x00'**

I googled and read the solution for this issue I am not able to resolve my issue. I am using Django 1.3.1, Python 2.7.3, tried MySQL Python connector 1.2.3 and 1.2.4 (but it does not resolve my issue). Below is my code

Models

```
class DbView(models.Model):
column1 = models.CharField(max_length=225, db_column='column1') # Field name made lowercase.
column2 = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='column2') # Field name made lowercase.
column3 = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='column3') # Field name made lowercase.
column4 = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='column4') # Field name made lowercase.
column5 = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_column='column5') # Field name made lowercase.
column6 = models.IntegerField(db_column='column6') # Field name made lowercase.
column7 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=9, db_column='column7') # Field name made lowercase.
column8 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=9, db_column='column8') # Field name made lowercase.
class Meta:
    db_table = u'db_view'
```

Views

```
def lookupTable(testtype):
if (testtype == 'Db'):
    return DbView

def queryTest(request,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,type,):      
rt=lookupTable(type).objects.using('dvt_wlan').filter(column2=val1,column4=val2,column5=val4,column3=val3,column1__contains=val5).values('column6').distinct('column6');
    #I tried to execute to run without using "distinct" part but it does not work
lTemp.append(rt[0]['column6']) #error comes here
lTemp.append(rt[1]['column6'])
lTemp.append(rt[2]['column6'])
```

I am trying to fire a query on **MySQL database view** which does not have any primary key using the django. I have one more database view and when I tried to run the same code on that view it actually works, so I am not understanding what exactly the issue is.

It does not give error me at that time but it gives an error when it tried to access the element i.e. rt[0]. Then I found out that actually database query is fired when we try to access it not at the time of evaluation. I checked in the debugger that "rt" is ValuesQuerySet type and but I can't access the element.

I also tried the running query by removing "filter" part in the above code but it is not working

Comment: Hello, 0x00 is equal to NULL, Maybe one of the values you're trying to assign is empty. Could you post here the value of all the variables ?? (You can visualize them in the error page if you click over **Local Vars** )

Comment: I checked all the values in the Local Variables Section in the error page and nothing is empty. So I guess that is not an issue.

Comment: The other thing I think about is the encoding, are you managing especial characters ?

Comment: That I thought as well. So I changed the encoding of the string but it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you show the value of rt before you do "rt[0]['column6']" ? The full content of rt. sorry for my obvious answers, just trying to help

Comment: When I try to use **print rt**. It gives me above error message: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '\x00' So I tried to run **print rt[0]** but it is giving me the same error.

Comment: But in the error page, when you check in Local Vars, what is inside rt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I guess it is not the proper solution but I don't have the choice as I was not getting help.

Solution:

Rather than using MySQL view (which actually created using couple of database tables) to run the command from Django. I, first, retrieve the columns from the first database table and then added them in the list and then run another query on the second database table.

```
for r in Table1.objects.using('schema1').filter(column1=val1,column2=val2).values('column3').distinct('column3'):
    ltest.append(r['column3'])
for r in lookupTable(type).objects.using('schema1').filter(column3__in=ltest).values('column4').distinct('column4'):
    lTemp.append(r['column4'])
```

Now it is working. So I guess, it may be that database view does not have primary key. So while creating model, Django automatically adds one "id" field which is primary key. In case of database table, they already have primary key, may be that's why I am not getting any issue.